# How do i make the pacman change sides when pressing the key

Tags: actionscript-3

So i have created a flash snake game and i can make the pacman snake move around, but how do i fix this code so that the face will go to the left frame which is frame 2 when i click left, and then go down when i click down on the keyboard which is frame 3 then the same for up which is frame 4.

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var score:int;
score = -10;


    stage.focus=stage; //This is coding to make the arrow keys work on the gamescreen straight away with no clicking

    // constants
     const gridSize:int = 20;
     const leftWall:int =100;  //There Dimensions for when the snake dies on the left wall i have changed these to fit around the border of my image and to make it suitable
     const rightWall:int = 580; //Dimensions for when the snake dies on the left wall i have changed these to fit around the border of my image and to make it suitable
     const topWall:int = 75; //Dimensions for when the snake dies on the left wall i have changed these to fit around the border of my image and to make it suitable
     const bottomWall:int = 385; //Dimensions for when the snake dies on the left wall i have changed these to fit around the border of my image and to make it suitable
     const startSpeed:int = 200; //Dimensions for when the snake dies on the left wall i have changed these to fit around the border of my image and to make it suitable
     const startPoint:Point = new Point(260,180);

    // game state
     var gameSprite:Sprite;
     var food:Food = new Food();
     var gameTimer:Timer;
     var snakeParts:Array;

    // snake velocity
     var snakeMoveX:Number = 0;
     var snakeMoveY:Number = 0;
     var nextMoveX:Number = 1;
     var nextMoveY:Number = 0;


        // create game sprite
        gameSprite = new Sprite();
        addChild(gameSprite);

        // create first part of snake
        snakeParts = new Array();
        var firstSnakePart = new SnakeHead(); //I have changed this to make two different parts to the snake so that it fits to my plans of the game
        firstSnakePart.x = startPoint.x;
        firstSnakePart.y = startPoint.y;
        snakeParts.push(firstSnakePart);
        gameSprite.addChild(firstSnakePart);

        // create first food
        gameSprite.addChild(food);
        placeFood();

        // set up listener and timer
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        gameTimer = new Timer(startSpeed);
        gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,moveSnake);
        gameTimer.start();


    // register key presses
     function keyDownFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            if (snakeMoveX != 1) {
                nextMoveX = -1;
                nextMoveY = 0;
                snakeHead2.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            if (snakeMoveX != -1) {
                nextMoveX = 1;
                nextMoveY = 0;
                snakeHead2.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            if (snakeMoveY != 1) {
                nextMoveY = -1;
                nextMoveX = 0;
                snakeHead2.gotoAndStop(4);
            }
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            if (snakeMoveY != -1) {
                nextMoveY = 1;
                nextMoveX = 0;
                snakeHead2.gotoAndStop(3);
            }
        }
    }

    // move snake one space in proper direction
     function moveSnake(event:TimerEvent) {         
        snakeMoveX = nextMoveX;
        snakeMoveY = nextMoveY;
        var newX:Number = snakeParts[0].x + snakeMoveX*gridSize;
        var newY:Number = snakeParts[0].y + snakeMoveY*gridSize;

        // check for collision
        if ((newX > rightWall) || (newX < leftWall) || (newY > bottomWall) || (newY < topWall)) {
            gameOver();
        } else if (hitTail()) {
            gameOver();
        } else {

            // check for food
            if ((newX == food.x) && (newY == food.y)) { //  This is placed into the game to check if any food is on the GameScreen, if there isn't then it will spawn the food.
                placeFood();
                newSnakePart();
                gameTimer.delay -= 2;
            }
            placeTail();
            snakeParts[0].x = newX;
            snakeParts[0].y = newY;
        }
    }

    // randomly place the food
     function placeFood() {

        score = score + 10; //This adds 10 points for every piece of food being picked up
        scoreField.text = score.toString(); 
        var startPoint: int ;
        startPoint = 80; //This makes the food spawn at least 80 pixels into the stage and around the stage meaning it won't go outside the borders
        var foodX:int = Math.floor(Math.random()* ( rightWall-leftWall)/gridSize)*gridSize + startPoint;
        var foodY:int = Math.floor(Math.random()* ( bottomWall-topWall)/gridSize)*gridSize + startPoint;
        food.x = foodX;
        food.y = foodY;
    }

    // add one sprite to snake
     function newSnakePart() {
        var newPart:SnakePart = new SnakePart();
        gameSprite.addChild(newPart);
        snakeParts.push(newPart);
        var mySound:Sound = new foodSound(); //Adds sound to the game when food spawns and the sound is a mario sound of picking up coins and plays when the food respawns
mySound.play(); //Just a instruction to make my sound play
    }

    // place all parts of snake
     function placeTail() {
        for(var i:int=snakeParts.length-1;i>0;i--) {
            snakeParts[i].x = snakeParts[i-1].x;
            snakeParts[i].y = snakeParts[i-1].y;
        }
    }

    // see if the head hit any part of the tail
     function hitTail() {
        for(var i:int=1;i<snakeParts.length;i++) {
            if ((snakeParts[0].x == snakeParts[i].x) && (snakeParts[0].y == snakeParts[i].y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // stop game
     function gameOver() {
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        gotoAndStop (3); //Once the user has died on the game, then this will take them to the end frame which is the third frame
        gameTimer.stop();
        removeChild (gameSprite) ; //This was added so that when the game does restart no food was shown from the previous games and doesn't cause any distractions
    }
```

Comment: you use `gotoAndStop()` - which is what I see in your code.  You need to be clearer about what your specific issue is.   Are you getting an error?  is the gotoAndStop() not being executed?

Comment: snakeHead2 isn't defined anywhere. You should probably write firstSnakePart.gotoAndStop(2) for left and so on.